# Is duplicate `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta key allowed?

Tags: post-meta

This line in my plugin:

```
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta ADD CONSTRAINT postmeta UNIQUE (post_id,meta_key(100))");
```

gives me the following error:

```
[Duplicate entry '539-_wp_attachment_image_alt' for key 'postmeta']
```

I looked for the entry in my database and saw several entries where `post_id` is 539 and `meta_key` is `_wp_attachment_image_alt`, as well as several others with duplicate `post_id`s and image alts.

My question is this: are duplicate `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta keys allowed in WordPress? I am trying to understand whether there was an error on this particular site at some point that duplicated the entries, or if it is a normal behaviour.

I know duplicate meta_keys in general can be inserted into the `postmeta` table, and I've also got a feeling I should not add and rely on a post_id+meta_key unique key since duplicate meta_keys are allowed in WordPress, right?

Comment: Duplicate entries for attachment image alt text is unusual, but duplicate meta keys is absolutely not unusual, and in some cases expected or recommended. There's nothing to gain from adding this constraint.

Comment: I use it to make sure a third-party program that connects to my plugin does not create duplicate entries every time it exports data to website, which happens several times a day.

Comment: Well you’ll break lots of things. WordPress is designed to support multiple meta keys. There’s dedicated functions for it and everything. If you have data that cannot have duplicate values then that’s something you need to enforce in the plugin that creates the data.

Comment: @Artem so this is an X Y problem? You should ask about your original problem, not how to fix your solution, you should do this at the plugins support routes, what you're trying to do here breaks a fundamental part of WordPress and will cause damage, it can never be the solution to your problem with the plugin.

Comment: @TomJNowell I asked my quesion to find out if duplicate meta keys are allowed. When I encountered this issue I understood I shouldn't have used this solution in the first place, but wanted to make sure duplicate meta keys weren't a glitch in my database. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Artem if you're just trying to avoid duplicates, then you could use `update_post_meta()` and not `add_post_meta()` when saving the meta. That way, the meta would simply be updated or added if not already exists. There's also [`metadata_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) that you can use to check if a meta exists, just as the name implies.

Comment: @Sally SJ hello! ) My scripts may deal with tens of thousands of entries at once, functions like `update_post_meta` or `add_post_meta` are way too slow for this. I import data from xml to a temporary table, then convert to meta with a single query like `UPDATE wp_postmeta t1 INNER JOIN wp_posts t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.ID INNER JOIN temp_table t3 ON t2.import_ID = t3.import_id SET meta_value = t3.barcode WHERE t1.meta_key='import_barcode'`. As I said, I'll have to re-design part of my code, just wanted to make sure meta keys not only can be, but are designed to be duplicated.

Comment: Yes, those functions may not be as fast as your SQL, but using the functions is the proper approach for manipulating WordPress post meta - one, so that the meta caches are updated, and secondly, so that plugins can take advantage of the meta hooks to run specific actions. As for the tens of thousands matter, you could run the import in batches in the background, e.g. via a WP Cron job or a library like [Action Scheduler](https://actionscheduler.org/). That's just a suggestion, though, or something that should be considered.

Comment: And in specific to the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta, yes, WordPress doesn't prohibit duplicating it, but an attachment post should only have one alt meta - if you have duplicates, they'll be updated to the same value if for example you used the media modal (wp-admin → Media → Library) to update the alt.

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, true! I've seen people try to reinvent a wheel in a mysql way where it wasn't really needed. I do use native functions where possible, otherwise why WordPress ) , and raw MySQL turned out to be handy to deal with [1C:Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1C:Enterprise), a business program that sends xml files over http.  As for my question, it turned out there were two to five (old) copies of every meta key in my database, I preferred to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418213/8646418) (in case someone with similar issue comes across this question)

Comment: Well, it's good that you found the culprit and a solution as well. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, it's always a pleasure to talk to you, I admire your knowledge and do implement your advice every time. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Meta keys are not unique**, a post can have multiple meta with the same key by design. Additionally, you should not be modifying WP core tables in your plugin, this is bad practice and can lead to data loss on WP updates.

In particular, the various meta APIs have a 3rd parameter:

```
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

If `$single` is set to `false` then an array of all key/value pairs is returned. This way you can store multiple values without resorting to serialised arrays. This is also why there are separate `update_post_meta` and `add_post_meta` functions.

The same is true of term/comment/user/site meta etc